# Why do I have to use a global for imported variable?

Tags: python

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

def get_one_week():
    global date
    seven_dates = []
    date = date.today()
    for i in range(7):
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        date_str = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        seven_dates.append(date_str)
    return seven_dates

print(get_one_week())
```

This will print out:

```
['20220901', '20220831', '20220830', '20220829', '20220828', '20220827', '20220826']
```

My question, both 'date' and 'datetime' are imported variables, but why do I have use a global declaration for the 'date' but not for the 'datetime' variable?

Comment: Don't reuse the imported name as a variable name. Your problem is here`date = date.today()`

Comment: Have you tried `datetime.date.today()`?

Comment: You are **assigning** to `date`, which is almost *certainly* not what you meant to do here.

Comment: But if I changed to 'today=date.today()', it complains that 'date' is not defined.

Comment: @marlon no, no it does not (note, you have to replace `date += datetime.timedelta(days=-1)` with `today += datetime.timedelta(days=-1)` as well

Comment: @marlon remove the global declaration in addition to renaming the variable

Comment: And also, `date_str = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')` to `date_str = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you declared your variable date so python thinks that you referenced the local variable before any assignment try change it to other name so it will use the global one

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

def get_one_week():
    seven_dates = []
    d = date.today()
    for i in range(7):
        d += datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        date_str = d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        seven_dates.append(date_str)
    return seven_dates
    
print(get_one_week())
```